# Error while loading .h5 model in Flask using keras

Tags: flask, keras

I have built a horse human detector using keras CNN on Google colab the model worked and loaded perfectly on colab. Now I am building a flask application while loading he .h5 model file I was getting error

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ragged'
```

I reinstall keras  2.3.1 using pip and now I am getting a library error

```
 NameError: name 'six' is not defined
```

my App.py

```
#Import necessary libraries
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

import numpy as np
import os

from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.models import load_model
 

#load model
model = load_model("predictor.h5" )
print("@@ model loaded")

def pred_human_horse(model , horse_or_human):
  test_image = load_img(horse_or_human , target_size=(150,150)) #resize
  print("@@ Got Image for predicton")
  test_image = img_to_array(test_image)/255 #numpy array  between 0-1
  test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image,axis=0) #4 dimension

  result= model.predict(test_image).round(3) #rounding off
  pred =np.argmax(result)
  print("@@ Raw results = ",result)
  print("@@ class = ", pred)

  if pred==0:
    return "Horse"

  else:
    return "Human"

# Crate flask app
app = Flask(__name__)
    
@app.route("/",methods=["GET","POST"])
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/predict",methods=["GET","POST"])
def predict():
    if request.method=="POST":
        #get input image file
        file = request.files["image"]
        filename= file.filename
        print("@@ File recieved",filename)
        
        #save the file
        file_path= os.path.join("static/user_uploaded",filename)
        file.save(file_path)
        
        print("@@ Prediction...")
        pred=pred_human_horse(horse_or_human=file_path )
        
        return render_template("predict.html" ,pred_output= pred , user_image=file_path )


if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(threaded=False)
```

Error I am getting

```
runfile('F:/INTERNSHIP/Crisp-Metric-MAY21/Human-horse-prediction/app.py', wdir='F:/INTERNSHIP/Crisp-Metric-MAY21/Human-horse-prediction')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-26-df590f092cb6>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('F:/INTERNSHIP/Crisp-Metric-MAY21/Human-horse-prediction/app.py', wdir='F:/INTERNSHIP/Crisp-Metric-MAY21/Human-horse-prediction')

  File "C:\Users\DANIA NIAZI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\DANIA NIAZI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "F:/INTERNSHIP/Crisp-Metric-MAY21/Human-horse-prediction/app.py", line 13, in <module>
    model = load_model("predictor.h5" )

  File "C:\Users\DANIA NIAZI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 492, in load_wrapper

  File "C:\Users\DANIA NIAZI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 582, in load_model

  File "C:\Users\DANIA NIAZI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\io_utils.py", line 211, in is_supported_type

NameError: name 'six' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try installing the *six* package which will be installed when installing Django. Anyway you can install it using:
`pip install six`